# Python - Convert a key-value string to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `Python` script that reads a string from a file which is have several `key=value` elements. An example is:

```
A=Astring,B=Bstring,C=Cstring
```

Is there an easy way to read this straight into a dictionary? Or would I have to manually build a dictionary after splitting by `,` and again by `=`.

Comment: Do you need to handle special case like `A="hello, 2+2==4",B=potato`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split with a generator expression and the `dict()` function:

```
d = dict(entry.split('=') for entry in inputstring.split(','))
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputstring = 'A=Astring,B=Bstring,C=Cstring'
>>> dict(entry.split('=') for entry in inputstring.split(','))
{'A': 'Astring', 'C': 'Cstring', 'B': 'Bstring'}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thnx!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply split based on `,` first and then for each item you can split based on `=`, like this

```
data = "A=Astring,B=Bstring,C=Cstring"
print dict(i.split("=") for i in data.split(","))
# {'A': 'Astring', 'C': 'Cstring', 'B': 'Bstring'}
```

Comment: Is there a performance advantage for passing a `list` to the `dict` function over a generator, like there is for the `.join` method of strings?  I'm asking because of your "If the string is longer..." comment.

Comment: @SethMMorton Yes. Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1903116)

Comment: @thefourtheye: No, that's not what Seth is asking. That answer shows the *exception*, where `str.join()` with a list comprehension is faster than a generator expression. **This is no such exception**.

Comment: @thefourtheye: in other words, you are wasting cycles and memory here by using a list comprehension. There is no join here, `dict()` will just iterate over the generator expression and not build a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for pointing out :) Removed that from the answer.

Comment: @SethMMorton: No, there is no performance advantage here; the `dict()` constructor simply iterates over the first argument (if it is not a `dict` instance itself), so passing in a list comprehension or a generator makes little difference. A generator expression will take less memory.